# Como usar implementações diferentes da mesma interface

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou com dificuldade de entender o diagrama e as especificações abaixo.

Como faço o método `double getCalculaFrete()` retornar o mesmo valor retornado pelo método `double calcularFretePedido()`, sendo chamado pela variável `calculaFrete` na classe `Pedido`, ou seja, `calculaFrete.calcularFretePedido()`?

E cada classe concreta que herda da classe abstrata `CalcularFrete` deverá retornar um valor `double` referente ao valor do seu frete. Um exemplo seria, um frete padrão custa R$ 3,50 e um frete expresso custa R$ 5,50.

> Crie dois objetos para testar esse programa na classe `Principal`. Para que o teste seja feito corretamente, os objetos precisam ser do tipo da classe `Pedido` e para mostrar o valor do frete de cada um basta acessar o método `double getCalculaFrete()` desse mesmo objeto, ou seja, considerando que um objeto foi criado com o seguinte nome:  `Pedido pedido1…` , para mostrar o valor do seu frete basta acionar o retorno de tal forma: `pedido1.getCalculaFrete()` e imprimi-lo.  Graças ao polimorfismo, o construtor da classe `Pedido` recebe qualquer objeto de uma dada classe que tenha um relacionamento "é um" com a classe abstrata.

Estou com dificuldade de imprimi-lo também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como `CalcularFrete` é uma classe abstrata, você pode deixar o método `calcularFretePedido` abstrato:

```
public abstract class CalcularFrete {
    public abstract double calcularFretePedido();
}
```

O que significa que as subclasses de `CalcularFrete` que devem ter suas regras específicas para saber o valor do frete. No seu caso, você teria o frete padrão retornando $3,50 e o frete expresso retornando $5,50:

```
public class CalculadoraFretePadrao extends CalcularFrete {
    // frete padrao, 3.50
    public double calcularFretePedido() {
        return 3.5;
    }
}

public class CalculadoraFreteExpresso extends CalcularFrete {
    // frete expresso, 5.50
    public double calcularFretePedido() {
        return 5.5;
    }
}
```

Agora você tem 2 classes que sabem calcular o frete, cada uma cuidando do seu tipo de frete específico (padrão ou expresso).

Já a classe `Pedido` possui um campo do tipo `CalcularFrete`. Ou seja, ela pode receber qualquer subclasse de `CalcularFrete`, e o valor de `freteCalculado()` vai ser retornado pelo tipo de frete que ele receber:

```
public class Pedido {
    private CalcularFrete calculaFrete;

    // recebe qualquer subclasse de CalcularFrete
    public Pedido(CalcularFrete calculaFrete) {
        this.calculaFrete = calculaFrete;
    }

    // retorna o valor do frete calculado
    public double freteCalculado() {
        return this.calculaFrete.calcularFretePedido();
    }
}
```

Para usar a classe `Pedido`, você passa no construtor o tipo de frete que você quer usar:

```
Pedido pedidoComFretePadrao = new Pedido(new CalculadoraFretePadrao());
double valorFretePadrao = pedidoComFretePadrao.freteCalculado(); // 3.5

Pedido pedidoComFreteExpresso = new Pedido(new CalculadoraFreteExpresso());
double valorFreteExpresso = pedidoComFreteExpresso.freteCalculado(); // 5.5
```